# Visual Studio Parsing Byte array into File sent from Android

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, byte

Im receiving a byte array to my C# server and having issues parsing it into File back again.

Some of the bytes im receiving have negative value, for example : -119, - 64.

When trying to parse the request im getting into Byte array, im receiving the following exception : `-119 is not a valid value for Byte.`

The android phone who sends me that, sends me a list of byte array, and im expecting `List<Byte[]>`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [`byte`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html) in Java is an eight-bit signed integer. In C# the [`byte`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bdb6693.aspx) type is unsigned, the corresponding type in C# is an [`sbyte`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d86he86x.aspx).

What you get is a `List<sbyte[]>`.

Comment: Accepted, with my kind regards :)

Answer (score 0):

If it's from Android, be careful with your data types. Java primitive types and .Net don't always match.

A [byte in java](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Byte.html) is signed and a [byte in .Net](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228360(v=vs.90).aspx) is unsigned.
You should use sbyte:

```
List<sbyte[]>
```